# How to invoke a function on a String in javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, function

Maybe this is weird, but I have one more question for the same GA API helper function.
I need strings which will specify filter conditions, but I don't know how to use it properly.
Basically I want to generate and return a string such as `"ga:medium==organic"` from this function call `medium.equals(organic)` where `var organic = "organic"` and `var medium = "ga:medium"`. I know how to work with the two strings to produce the output, and there are a lot more conditions to code for, but I just need to know how to invoke the function on the string `medium` and then how to use both the invoking object (string) and the arguments to return an output. Is what I'm asking possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add methods to the string object and then refer to `this` to access the string you're operating on.

```
String.prototype.equals = function(arg) {
    return this + "==" + arg;
}

var medium = "ga:medium";
var organic = "organic";
var output = medium.equals(organic);   // "ga:medium==organic"
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/hNLy6/

Answer (score 0):

If your question is to compare two string logically and not as objects:

You can make use of the "===" operator which compares two operands for logical equality as
well as the type of the operands.

Example:

var x="5";

x==="5" // returns true

x===5   // returns false

Refer to this: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp